# Import could not be resolved but program runs

Tags: python

I'm learning to code in python and importing my own modules. The modules are in the same directory. This is my code:

main.py

```
from test import hallo,myAge,myDriver,Fahrzeug
from person import goodbye,Persona

    def main():
        
        print("---Start Test---")
    
        hallo()
        print(myDriver)
        print(myAge)
    
        opel = Fahrzeug(26,110,"Zafira")
        print(opel.getGeschwindigkeit())
    
        print("---Person---")
        
        goodbye()
        emil = Persona("Emil",22)
        print(emil.getName())
    
        print("---End Test---")
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

test.py

```
#Random Variables
myDriver = "Hans"
myAge = 47

#Random Function
def hallo():
    print("Hallo I'm your driver")

#Class
class Fahrzeug:
    geschwindigkeit = 0
    ps = 0
    name = ""

    def __init__(self, gesch, p, nam):
        self.geschwindigkeit = gesch
        self.ps = p
        self.name = nam

    def getGeschwindigkeit(self):
        return self.geschwindigkeit
```

person.py

```
def goodbye():
    print("Goodbye")

class Persona:
    name = ""
    alter = 0

    def __init__(self,na,alt):
        self.name = na
        self.alter = alt

    def getName (self):
        return self.name
```

I get following problem message:

```
Import "person" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports) [2,6]
```

If I run the program, the program will still work despite the message. Why do I get the problem message?

[My View in Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Br6Mz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `settings.json` file you have to add the paths from which you import what's needed in extraPaths i.e the path to the root of your project:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/home/youruser/.virtualenvs/app-FzQGSFjf/bin/python",
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["app", "another/path/etc"]
}
```

Also, I notice that you have saved your module inside `.vscode` folder, try to move your module out of the `.vscode` folder as the `.vscode` folder is usually reserved for VSCode related settings and not your project source code

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now I added the path `"python.analysis.extraPaths" :["C:/Users/ricci/Documents/Programming Projects/Klib/Play"]` to the `setting.json` file and moved all the modules out of the `.vscode` folder. I'm still getting the problem message. All the modules are in the "Play" Folder. Do I have to import the path into the code in the `main.py` file?